# Property in array pass null value but it doesn't null anyway Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of interface which name is `IProject[]` and I get values of API and the API and values response correctly... but when I want to get the value of array in my component.html or component.ts it return me Undefined. But I log the array and it showed me the value correctly.
It drives me crazy because it's not an error and I don't know what should I look for!

My code

```
  //Get Value From Api
  getProjects():Observable<IProject[]>{
    return this.http.get<IProject[]>(this.baseUrl+"/Get/GetProjects");
  }
```

Component.ts

```
 //Call methode to get values
 ngOnInit(){
 this.getProjects();

 }

 //Call methode in services I wrote on the top
 getProjects(){
   this.homeService.getProjects(this.eN).subscribe({
   next:(response)=>{this.projects=response},
   error:(error)=>{console.log(error)}
 });
```

if I log the `projects` variable it returns my values...
but if I use it in for or use it like it `projects[0].topic`
it will return Undefined

Comment: it looks like the object has not got the `projects[0].topic`  property. Can you show the `IProject` interface

Comment: @hawks export interface IProject{
    id:number;
    topic:string;
    detail:string;
}

Comment: It can be from the ngOninit hook, angular may instantiate the component before subscribing to the service. can you provide how did you define this.project in the component?

Comment: @hous I defined this.projects like this ' projects:IProject[]; '

Comment: it sooooooooo weird because I use  another array which I didn't need that any more and that worked for me :).

Comment: yes it can happen because of the time of subscribing may be different, Try to do this instead: `projects:IProject[] = []`

Answer (score 0):

Since you retrieve the projects in `ngOnInit`, the projects variable will be undefined until the API call completes. There's multiple ways to solve this, pick whichever one you prefer:

- Add `*ngIf="projects"` to your HTML template
- Set the initial value of projects to an empty array
- Use a [resolver service](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-route-resolvers) to retrieve data beforehand